# The proper way to increment my binary tree

Tags: c++, class, c++11, iterator, unique-ptr

Here is the class I've created

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T> 
class binary_tree {

private:
    T t_data;
    std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>> t_left, t_right;
    
    class binary_tree_iterator {                  // -----------------------
    private:
        T data;
    public:                                       
        binary_tree_iterator(T d) : data(d) {}    //     Iterator class
        T& operator*() {return data;}
        binary_tree_iterator& operator++() {} // <--------- ??????
    };                                            
                                                  // ------------------------
public:
    binary_tree(T d) : t_data(d), t_left(nullptr), t_right(nullptr)
    {}
    
    void insert(T data) {
        if(data <= t_data) {
            if(t_left == nullptr) {
                t_left = std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>>(new binary_tree<T>(data));
            } else {
                t_left->insert(data);
            }          
        } else {
            if(t_right == nullptr)
                t_right = std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>>(new binary_tree<T>(data));
            else
                t_right->insert(data);
        }
    }
    
    const T data() const {
        return t_data;
    }
    
    const std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>>& left() const {
        return t_left;
    }
    
    const std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>>& right() const {
        return t_right;
    }
    
    binary_tree_iterator begin() {      
        if(t_left == nullptr) {
            return binary_tree_iterator(t_data);
        } else {
            return t_left->begin();
        }
    }
    
    binary_tree_iterator end() {
        if(t_right == nullptr) {
            return binary_tree_iterator(t_data);
        } else {
            return t_right->end();
        }
    }
};
```

I've declared my iterator class inside of my container class. This may have been a mistake but either way I'm not sure how to define my overloaded increment function. Once I've found begin() I've lost my way back. It seems like unique_ptr() is designed for one way pointing. Assuming I have to use unique_ptr in this fashion, is there some work around here? I've thought about giving each instance of binary_tree a head member that points back from whence it came, but each node should only be accessible from the node above it. I make some sort of index but that seems to completely defeat the purpose of this container type. I'm solving exercise so I'm restricted to using the unique_ptr.

Comment: unique_ptr is used for memory management, not for organising trees.Try to use normal pointers for that!

Comment: Using a unique_ptr indicates that the class with the unique_ptr 'owns' the pointed at object, and is responsible for deleting it. This make (some) sense for the pointers that tree nodes hold to their children, it makes no sense for the parent pointers that you need, because a child doesn't own it's parent (rather it's the other way around). Just use a raw pointer for this purpose.

Comment: @U.W. `unique_ptr` is *very suitable* for the child pointers in a tree

Comment: @john I need left() and right() members to return unique_ptr  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Joemoor94 Now that really does make no sense. If you have getter methods called `left()` and `right()` returning a unique pointer then that implies that they are transferring ownership of the left or right child (which make no sense) or that they are allocating a new child node and returning a unique pointer to it (which also makes no sense).

Comment: I agree with U.W. I would not use unqiue_ptr at all in a tree, rather I would manage the nodes in the tree class itself instead of delegating that to a utility class like unique_ptr. But Caleth disagrees, which is fine, it's really a matter of style.

Answer (score 5):

You defined your iterator as containing the `data` value in your tree.

This is not what iterators are all about. Iterators do not contain the value they're referencing, but rather a reference (in the common meaning of the word, and not a C++ term) to it, typically a pointer.

Of course you can't figure out what to do with `++`. For your iterator, it is natural to expect that the `++` operator will advance the iterator to the next node in your tree, but since the iterator does not contain a pointer to anything, you have nothing to advance there, and run into a mental block.

You will need to redesign your iterator so that it contains a pointer to your `binary_tree`; its `*` overload dereferences; and the `++` advances to the next element in your binary tree, which it will then be able to do, using its pointer.

At this point you will run into another mental block. Iterating through an entire binary tree requires, at some point, to back up to parent nodes in the tree. After all, after recursing into the `left` part of the binary tree, at some point, after iterating through the binary tree you will need to, somehow, in some way, wind up in the `right` part of the binary tree. However, as designed, your `binary_tree` has no means of navigating to any node's parent. That's another design flaw you will need to address, in some fashion.

It is possible, I suppose, to implement this entire backtracking in the iterator itself, having the iterator record each node its visited, so it can back up to it, when needed. But iterators are supposed to be lightweight objects, barely more than a pointer themselves, and not a full blown data structure that implements complicated operations.

In summary, you have several holes in the design of your binary tree that you will need to address, before you can implement an effective iterator for it.

Comment: You're telling me